# Is it possible to make <script type=application/ld+json> connect to external file?

Tags: seo, schema

Is it possible to use

```
<script type=application/ld+json src='page1.schema.json'>
```

Instead of inline:

```
<script type=application/ld+json>{.....}</script>
```

I think it'd be very helpful to save page's size because these content are not for user but for Google bots only.